# How do I track down what went wrong when an email to AWS-SES goes missing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I ran every step in
[Getting Started Receiving Email with Amazon SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started.html)
and all went smoothly. I left the [receipt rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started-receipt-rule.html)
open so that any email address is accepted.
But when I send an email to `joe@example.com` (for my own `example.com`), no files are created in the S3 bucket.
The file `AMAZON_SES_SETUP_NOTIFICATION` is there all right, but nothing else.

How do I go about debugging this issue? Where does one track down what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a rule for "domain.com" as a recipient which will match for all emails for this domain email addresses. 
Couple of things you can check:

1. MX record for your domain should point to SES inbound endpoint (changing MX may break your incoming emails if you're using it somewhere else already)
2. Is the rule-set where you have created the rule active ? There can only be one rule-set active.
3. S3 permission, S3 bucket requires a bucket policy to allow put object from SES.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-permissions.html

4. To debug , check if you have received any bounce back.